# Rashes on thigh after running

Tags: weight-loss, injury-prevention, jogging

I am trying to loose my weight, by jogging/running for about 18-20 minutes in the morning.

But the issue that i am having is that after a jogging session i get rashes on high thighs, giving at least one day lull in the programme; resulting in breaking the regularity/punctuality.

I want to get rid of the rashes, any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming the chafing is where your thighs are rubbing. Longer shorts, long underwear and bodyglide will help cut the chafing.

Comment: Also wearing tighter, stretching clothing is less likely to rub as much

Comment: Do these tighter, longer shorts need to be compression apparel or just longer and preferably seamless fabric?

Comment: Whatever is comfortable. Seams may or may not make a difference, and it doesn't necessarily need to be compression. You just have to try different ones out and see what works for you.